# How can I hide the error message "There was an error while copying to the Clipboard. An internal error occurred."

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, clipboard

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro X on Windows 7 x64 SP1. I keep having the error message "There was an error while copying to the Clipboard. An internal error occurred." while I hit Ctrl+C. The message is mistaken as copying to the Clipboard does work.

Is there any way to hide the following error window:

[image]

?

It's annoying to have to close it each time I need to copy something in Adobe Acrobat Pro X.

Answer (score 8):

Edit --> Preferences --> Security (Enhanced) --> Uncheck "Enable protected mode at startup" (or "Enable enhanced security).

It worked for me, but looks like some people still have problems.

From https://forums.adobe.com/message/2005962 by "paulh"

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10, right-click Start, go to System, then Clipboard and turn Clipboard history off. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have idm:

   - go to downloads->settings->general->uncheck automatically start downloading links
     from clipboard.
   - For mine it was idm that caused problem. (Internet download manager)
2. If you don't have idm:

   - check your os, is there any software on it that monitors clipboard... if there is, turn it off.